# Rotating image cut off at sides buffered image, image icon, java

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, imageicon

[image]

```
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(paramString));
    double locationX = img.getWidth(this) / 2;
    double locationY = img.getHeight(this) / 2;
    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(paramInt3), locationX, locationY);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage (img.getWidth(this), img.getWidth(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
    bimg = op.filter (img, null);
    ImageIcon localImageIcon = new ImageIcon (bimg);
```

Why might the side be cut off?
I'm using a library that requires the end result to be a ImageIcon.

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: My code rotates the image but the corners are cut off at the top and left sides

Answer (score 0):

Your destination image is created here:

```
BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage (img.getWidth(this), img.getWidth(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
```

It's a square! If your source image is not a square you should create a destination image like this:

```
BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage (img.getHeight(this), img.getWidth(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image is square and the corners still get cut of at the top and left side.

Comment: While obviously a mistake, this isn't really the issue, as the `bimg` reference is overwritten on the next line. Maybe @ogprogrammingsquad meant `op.filter (img, bimg);`? When passing `null` as the output parameter, the destination is created.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a rounding problem:

```
double locationX = img.getWidth(this) / 2;
double locationY = img.getHeight(this) / 2;
```

Width and height are integers, if they are not even you might get rounding issues. Try this:

```
double locationX = ((double)img.getWidth(this)) / 2;
double locationY = ((double)img.getHeight(this)) / 2;
```